# AWS Cognito UserPool Alternative in China

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, user-management

I am searching for an alternative user management service in China as AWS Cognito UserPool is not yet available in China regions. The basic requirements are:
a. User Management
b. Authentication
c. Token Management

Any suggestions?

Thanks